# Update large number of rows in postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

The table contains around 80k existing rows.
I want to add a new column and want to update its value with the existing column's value.

What could be the better approach?

1. Batch update
2. Cursor to iterate through the rows and apply a separate update to each one
3. Hot table in postgres.

Please help.

Comment: Fastest is probably to drop indexes, perform update in a single command, recreate indexes

Comment: Run a `VACUUM (FULL)` after the update and before creating the indexes to get rid of bloat.

Comment: @404   As you said, it would be nice to perform update in single command. Will that not lead to prolong lock on table?

Comment: @girlwhocode Potentially. Depends how long the update takes, whether other processes access it for read-only or write. 80k records really isn't that much, I wouldn't expect it to take long at all if there are no indexes. You could always create a copy of that table and test it there.